# Vlookup with multiple matches in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

My data looks like:

```
id   state   value
1     abc      x
1     bcd      y
1     def      z
2     abc      p
2     bcd      q
2     def      r
3     bcd      m
3     def      n
```

I am trying to vlookup the value for id 1, 2 and so on, but where the state is not abc. Excel automatically picks the first entry and I tried with if condition on the column but am unable to get it work. I even tried Index  Match with an if condition inside match, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way I could do it?

Comment: @Scott Craner that does not solve my question

Comment: Could you please explain this? I am unable to implement it

Comment: Also, gsheets does not recognize the aggregate function

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Filter:

```
=index(filter(C2:C9,A2:A9=1,B2:B9<>"abc"),1)
```

[image]

if you want all that meet the criteria, remove the INDEX wrapper:

```
filter(C2:C9,A2:A9=1,B2:B9<>"abc")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(C:C, B:B<>"abc", REGEXMATCH(A:A&"", "1|2"))
```

[image: 0]

---

or just:

```
=FILTER(C:C, B:B<>"abc")
```

for partial `abc` you can do:

```
=FILTER(C:C, NOT(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "abc")))
```